# Generating a pdf report (eg personality report) from mysql database

Tags: mysql, pdf

Background: I want to hire someone (not here - just background) to take information inputted through WordPress (eg a personality test) and enable a pdf report to be automatically generated. The pdf would have to have some preset paragraphs(eg result Y gets turned into paragraph Y) and graphs showing the strength of various personality traits [eg CPI260 Report](https://ap.themyersbriggs.com/content/Sample%20Reports/219350.pdf). I have the testing side sorted but not the pdf reporting.

My Question: I have searched and searched online, but all I can find is advice on turning an HTML page into a pdf. **What coding language would I use?** I can't really search for someone to help me until I know what they need to be proficient with. Any additional advice would be welcome and appreciated.

Comment: There are pdf creator libraries for most popular programming languages, so we cannot objectively help you. Search for <programming language> create pdf.

Comment: There some js plugins that can help you, search in google for "html to pdf javascript"